# BYTE data type variable value in debugger

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, byte, cs50

This is in relation to my last post about finding the start of JPEGs and creating new jpg files with each new found JPEG. I am only getting part of one JPEG after running the below code (instead of the 50 that I know are in my card.raw file) and I am trying to run the debugger to find the issue. I am looking into my buffer to see why this is only executing the if(buffer[]...) statement once and dont understand how to read the value of what the debugger is showing me under local variables. [image]

I am trying to compare the first four values to the hex values for a JPEG file signature and these BYTE values make no sense to me. If someone could please shed some light. Here is my code as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// using keyword typedef to give the uint8_t a new name of BYTE (capitalized by convention)
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // must be two arguments or program not run correctly
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover filename\n");
        return 1;
    }

// open file and store its location in a pointer called infile
FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(infile == NULL)
{
    printf("file cannot be opened or doesnt exist...\n");
    return 1;
}

// create buffer to store a filename with a formatted string of ###.jpg starting at 000.jpg
int number = 0;
char filename[8];
sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", number);

FILE *img = NULL;

// read using fread(), each 512 byte block into a buffer
//need a buffer of size 512 BYTEs
BYTE buffer[512];
while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, infile))
{

    // this demarks a JPEG using bitwise logical & for last buffer bit of signature
    if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        if(number == 0)
        {
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            if(img == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to open file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
        }
        else
        {
            fclose(img);

            number ++;
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", number);

            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            if(img == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to open file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
        }
    }
    else if(img != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't they make sense for you? What values do you expect? Are you aware that the representation is decimal and octal? Or for printable characters it is decimal character symbol.

Comment: If the signature bytes are not there, then it's a data block of the jpeg file that is only meaningful in its context. You can't look at a single byte and say what it means, although the debugger is showing the byte value in different representations.

Comment: So it represents it both as a decimal value (the first three numbers) and any characters can be derived from the ASCII chart? Why do they give two representations of the same number?

Comment: Probably because they might think it could be useful for the user.

Comment: Just to be helpful. The debugger has no idea what the data is supposed to represent. Note that if no data has yet been read from file then the uninitialised buffer contains junk.

Comment: On a sidenote: `&buffer` is wrong. Just use `buffer` for `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: Got it thank you, I was unaware they would give two representations of the same value. Also Weather Vane thank you for your continued help! Code looking better than my last post, getting closer. I appreciate both of your feedback!

Comment: it's simply because the debugger doesn't know that you want the character value or the integer value of a `char` variable so it shows both

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with the code, but there again it is still more complicated than it needs to be. For example you have three `fwrite()` statements, although that needs to be done once no matter what else happens. So that can be the last unconditional statement of the `while` loop.